# AJAX query isn't functioning when passed a string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

### Explanation

I have the following code in PHP that allows the user to select a name from a drop-down, then pass that name as a string over to a JavaScript function:

```
<?php
                include('./db.php');
                $PM = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT PMName FROM report WHERE PMname <> '' ORDER BY PMName ASC");
                ?>
                <select class="navbar-inverse" placeholder="PM Name" name="PMName" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
                <?php
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($PM)) {
                $selected = array_key_exists('PMName', $_POST) && $_POST['PMName'] == $row[0] ? ' selected' : '';
                printf(" <option value='%s' %s>%s</option>\n", $row[0], $selected, $row[0]);
                }
                ?>
```

The JavaScript function then reads the string:

```
function showUser(str) {
  if (str !==".PM") {
    if (str=="") {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
    } 
  }
  $("#txtHint").load( "getuser.php?q="+str );
    console.log(str);
}
```

and is supposed to place the output of **`getuser.php?q=John%Doe`** into the **txtHint** DIV.

### Issue

the **str** value does not APPEAR to be fully passing into the 
`$("#txtHint").load( "getuser.php?q="+str );` line of code.

When I look at my console, I see the following once the JavaScript function fires:

```
HR finished loading: GET "http://localhost/getuser.php?q=John"
John Doe
```

If I change the code to read just `$("#txtHint").load( "getuser.php?q=");`, (without passing the `str` variable,) it works fine and loads the getuser.php page into the DIV, (of course, without a name I don't get back any info, but it works...)

What am I doing wrong here?  If the `console.log(str)` is outputting `John Doe`, then obviously the entire string is `John Doe`, so why is my console outputting `?q=John`? and causing getuser.php not to load into the DIV?

I'm very confused here....

Comment: Always read the documentation, if you had, you would notice that there is a data argument for `load`, and you can just do `$("#txtHint").load( "getuser.php", {q : str} );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode your string if you want to send it as a query variable:

```
$("#txtHint").load( "getuser.php?q="+encodeURIComponent(str));
```

Comment: Beauty.  Thank you!  I figured it had something to do with encoding the actual string.